# devise-async not executing enqueue jobs with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6, devise-async

I was working with devise and devise-async and it was sending emails with sidekiq using devise-async.
But recently it stops to work and I am not able to find the issue.

Gems I'm using

```
    gem 'devise'
    gem 'devise-async'
```

config/initilizer/devise-async.rb

```
Devise::Async.setup do |config|
  config.enabled = true
end
```

passwords_controller.rb

```
  def create
   #Here im sending emails with the below command
   self.resource =resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
  end
```

user.rb

```
  devise :database_authenticatable,:async,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable
```

im running sidekiq with the command

```
 sidekiq -q default -q mailer
```

Sidekiq.rb

```sh
config = YAML.load(ERB.new(IO.read(Rails.root + 'config' + 'redis.yml')).result)[Rails.env].with_indifferent_access

redis_conn = {url: "redis://localhost:6379/0"}

Sidekiq.configure_server do |s|
  s.redis = redis_conn
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |s|
  s.redis = redis_conn
end
```

Sidekiq Enqueued jobs in mailer queue but not sending it forward.

My Terminal Response

```
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.754589 #51261] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "moontesting@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.755562 #51261] DEBUG -- :   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/passwords_controller.rb:10:in `create'
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.821428 #51261] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["reset_password_token", "113ee2379de9d55cccce204afba81fea68dcfd6e0a168a031e144d518f"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.821880 #51261] DEBUG -- :   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/passwords_controller.rb:10:in `create'
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.823659 #51261] DEBUG -- :    (0.4ms)  BEGIN
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.824224 #51261] DEBUG -- :   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/passwords_controller.rb:10:in `create'
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.825034 #51261] DEBUG -- :   User Update (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "reset_password_token" = $1, "reset_password_sent_at" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["reset_password_token", "113ee2379de9d55cccce20422afba81fea68dcfda18a031e144d518f"], ["reset_password_sent_at", "2021-09-16 14:20:07.822110"], ["updated_at", "2021-09-16 14:20:07.822562"], ["id", 2]]
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.825480 #51261] DEBUG -- :   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/passwords_controller.rb:10:in `create'
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.834650 #51261] DEBUG -- :   PaperTrail::Version Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("item_type", "item_id", "event", "whodunnit", "object", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["item_type", "User"], ["item_id", "2"], ["event", "update"], ["whodunnit", "Unknown user"], ["object", "---\nreset_password_token: 78e745c5b2f23d539cbfcbd024209173539865e40da2885cfadfa72fbc4f1e6c\nreset_password_sent_at: 2021-09-16 14:15:51.921573000 Z\nid: 2\nfirst_name: moon\nlast_name: abc\nemail: moontesting10@gmail.com\nencrypted_password: \"$2a$11$8pi21jeHYC46FPJ/UEjLlOtNzoIkkZ/QooN68VpjWWuIUUqtICeWm\"\nremember_created_at: \nsign_in_count: 0\ncurrent_sign_in_at: \nlast_sign_in_at: \ncurrent_sign_in_ip: \nlast_sign_in_ip: \nconfirmation_token: \nconfirmed_at: \nconfirmation_sent_at: \nunconfirmed_email: \nfailed_attempts: 0\nunlock_token: \nlocked_at: \ncreated_at: 2021-09-16 12:06:20.985299000 Z\nupdated_at: 2021-09-16 14:15:51.921944000 Z\norganization_id: \npassword_changed_at: \ndeleted_at: \n"], ["created_at", "2021-09-16 14:20:07.822562"]]
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.835285 #51261] DEBUG -- :   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/passwords_controller.rb:10:in `create'
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.838491 #51261] DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  COMMIT
D, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.838981 #51261] DEBUG -- :   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/passwords_controller.rb:10:in `create'
I, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.853680 #51261]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: d49ca82c-6418-4848-8268-3ec72407f828) to Sidekiq(mailers) with arguments: "Devise::Mailer", "reset_password_instructions", "deliver_now", {:args=>[#<GlobalID:0x000055ee3c2adac0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://portal/User/2>>, "bGhQf9WdhEN_sj2pA1TT", {}]}
I, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.859059 #51261]  INFO -- :   Rendering api/v1/passwords/create.json.jbuilder
I, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.859715 #51261]  INFO -- :   Rendered api/v1/passwords/create.json.jbuilder (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 226)
I, [2021-09-16T19:20:07.860110 #51261]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 1846ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 10.8ms | Allocations: 118648)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because ActionMailer uses the `mailers` queue as default queue to send emails.

Sneakers also using mailers queue to send emails by default. But there is no Worker for queue named mailers.

By adding the following line in my `application.rb` solved my issue.

```html
config.action_mailer.deliver_later_queue_name = 'default'
```